# Jupyter Notebook ImportError, %matplotlib qt

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am using

```
%matplotlib inline
```

to display plots inside the notebook. I would like to disable this for several cells. So, I try

```
%matplotlib qt
```

This outputs the following error:

```
ImportError: Matplotlib qt-based backends require an external PyQt4, PyQt5,
or PySide package to be installed, but it was not found.
```

I am not sure how to solve this, as everything is up to date.

1. How can I solve the above?
2. Is there another way to disable `%matplotlib inline` in a certain cell without restarting the entire kernel?

Comment: What platform are you using? How did you install matplotlib?

Comment: Is your goal just to just suppress plotting for some lines, or do you actually want to open external plot windows?

Comment: @ali_m The latter. The plots are too large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *might* be able to use [`plt.switch_backend`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=switch_backend#matplotlib.pyplot.switch_backend), although as the documentation states, this is an experimental feature. The following works for me, using matplotlib 1.5 and an IPython 4.0.1:

```
In [1]: from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

In [2]: import numpy as np

# plot appears inline (default)
In [3]:plt.plot(np.random.randn(10))
Out[3]:[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7fac4408e390>]

In [4]: plt.switch_backend('QtAgg4')

# plot appears inside a separate Qt4 window
In [5]:plt.plot(np.random.randn(10))
Out[5]:[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7fac3b408a90>]
```

You might need to change `'QtAgg4'` according to whichever version of PyQt you have installed - this could be the cause of the error you mentioned in the question. Another interactive backend that should work on Mac would be `'CocoaAgg'`. If the images are very large you could also use the `'Agg'` backend to suppress plotting altogether, and instead save the resulting figure(s) straight to disk.

Comment: " instead save the resulting figure(s) straight to disk." That's basically what I've done. I'm just annoyed that `%matplotlib qt` doesn't work. Time to open an issue...

Comment: Before you open an issue, how sure are you that you actually have PyQt4, PyQt5 or PySide installed?

Comment: Agreed. Uninstalling and re-installing now.

Comment: Also, note that even if you do have one of the Qt backends installed, the `%matplotlib` magic will only allow you to switch backends if you haven't already started an interactive matplotlib session. Since `~$ ipython notebook` will usually start an interactive session using the `inline` backend by default, you should not expect `%matplotlib qt` to work within a running session. Use `plt.switch_backend` instead.

Comment: I came here for a different problem, but I would like to remark that @ali_m response gave me the solution: `CocoaAgg` just made my matplotlib setup in Mac work out-of-the-box after a couple of days struggling with `QtAgg4` + `PySide`, which returned me the same error output described in the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have a specific backend installed use "agg":

```
    import matplotlib
    matplotlib.use('agg')
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Reference: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9017